# In MSVS Ultimate 2013, it's not hitting breakpoints that it absolutely should be hitting. What's causing this and how can I fix it?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-debugging

"The Breakpoint will not currently be hit. No executable code is associated with this line. Possible causes include: conditional compilation or compiler optimizations." is the message I get when I hover over the breakpoints which aren't being hit.  I am in debug mode, and I know for a fact that it IS executing the code presented here, or at least a copy of it, as this code is in the middle of a series of cryptographic hash functions and the correct output is being produced from the given input.

Recently I'd also been having a similar problem that I could work around with a bit of annoyance, which was that when I hit "build", it would build and display warnings and errors correctly, but wouldn't actually execute any changes in code unless I did a full rebuild.  I suspect that these issues are related.

Now, it seems that a full rebuild is no longer sufficient, so I'm forced to go after the root of the problem.  Any help with diagnosing this is much appreciated.  If it matters, the code itself is c++, and I'm running windows 8.1.

Comment: Is the code in your executable or in a DLL?

Comment: Please post the solution as an Answer, rather than editing it into your question

Answer (score 0):

Checking the box for "Native Code Debugging" solved the problem.